# Pare down a variable to all before 1st space

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd, directory

**BACKGROUND:**
Have the following code. Lines 5 & 6 are the most important here:

`@echo off`

`setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`

`pushd "%~dp0" || exit /B`

`move /Y "Folder2.jpg" "Folder.jpg"`

**This line 5** `for %%I in (.) do set "FOLDER=%%~nxI"`

**This line 6** `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\gallery-dl\gallery-dl.exe" -d "U:\11Web\gallery-dl" --download-archive "%~dp0zzzGDB.sqlite3" "https://www.pixiv.net/en/users/%FOLDER%/illustrations"`

`if not errorlevel 1 if exist "zzzGDB.sqlite3" del "Folder.jpg"`

`popd`

`endlocal`

In Windows Explorer I create a folder (for example) named "18604150". Any folders I create will have a folder name of varying lengths. The code above is in a .bat file within that folder. Upon executing the code, line 5 assigns folder name "18604150" to the variable and line 6 inserts/calls it as part of the hyperlink:

https://www.pixiv.net/en/users/%FOLDER%/illustrations

equates to

https://www.pixiv.net/en/users/18604150/illustrations

All is well.

**PROBLEM:**
I want to be able to **ALWAYS** name folders as with the aforementioned numerical string at the beginning but **IN SOME CASES** also manually append artist name and/or other details to *the folder name*. Problem is I need to do this without "breaking" the variable and making it unusable for the hyperlink. Folder names could take on many shapes but will always begin with an unbroken first string of numbers. Examples:

18604150 -59 Bob Marley-

4839 Dan the Man

19374759394727 Scooby Snack 43443

I need to pare the variable down to only the digits left of any first SPACE, when present.

18604150

4839

19374759394727

I'm guessing whatever the solution will likely have to be in Line 5, but I do not know what this would look like.

`for %%I in (.) do set "FOLDER=%%~nxI"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little trial and error got my answer. Thanks goes to https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

`@echo off`

`setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`

`pushd "%~dp0" || exit /B`

`move /Y "Folder2.jpg" "Folder.jpg"`

`for %%I in (.) do set "FOLDER=%%~nxI"`

`for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ("%FOLDER%") do set FOLDER=%%a`

`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\gallery-dl\gallery-dl.exe" -d "U:\11Web\gallery-dl" --download-archive "%~dp0zzzGDB.sqlite3" "https://www.pixiv.net/en/users/%FOLDER%/illustrations"`

`if not errorlevel 1 if exist "zzzGDB.sqlite3" del "Folder.jpg"`

`popd`

`endlocal`

`pause`